# How can I get the least significant byte of a variable in C

Tags: c, byte

I'm trying to write a C function that will print a word consisting of the least signiﬁcant
byte of x, and the remaining bytes of y. For example if x = 0x89ABCDEF and y =
0x76543210, this should give 0x765432EF, but how?

Comment: are x & y both 4 bytes length, or they may differ ??

Comment: `(y & ~0xff) | (x & 0xff)`

Comment: yes x and y are the same length

Answer (score 13):

In order to manipulate specific bits (or bytes) within a data type, you should use the bit-wise operators.

The basic bit-wise operators are | (or), & (and), ^ (exclusive or), and ~ (NOT or complement), and they work very differently from the logical operators ||, &&, and !.

Using your variables x = 0x89ABCDEF and y = 0x76543210, let's step through a solution:

First, these are the values of x and y in binary:

```
    x = 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
    y = 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0001 0000
```

I've split the 32 bits up into groups of 4 to see how hex translates to binary.

Now, we need to unset all but the last byte in x: the operation (x & 0xFF)

```
           x = 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
        0xFF = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
    --------------------------------------------------
    x & 0xFF = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 1111
```

And we need to unset just the last byte of y: the operation (y & ~0xFF)

```
              y = 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0001 0000
          ~0xFF = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 (~ flips all bits)
    -----------------------------------------------------
    (y & ~0xFF) = 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0000 0000
```

Now, combine our results using the "or" operation: (x & 0xFF) | (y & ~0xFF)

```
                  (x & 0xFF) = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 1111
                 (y & ~0xFF) = 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0000 0000
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    (x & 0xFF) | (y & ~0xFF) = 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 1110 1111
    Which in hex is------------7----6----5----4----3----2----E----F
```

Take some time to get familiar with these operations, and you shouldn't have any trouble. Also, make sure to learn other bitwise operators (<<, >>, &=, |=, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```
inline uint32_t combine(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  return (y & 0xffffff00) | (x & 0xff);
}
```

Here's an example (see the result [here](http://ideone.com/YL0PR)).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

inline uint32_t combine(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  return (y & 0xffffff00) | (x & 0xff);
}

main() {
  printf("%" PRIx32 "\n", combine(0x89abcdef, 0x76543210));
}
```